# In Odoo 13 How can I limit access to an eLearning slide?

Tags: python, xml, odoo-13

I'm trying to build functionality that requires those enrolled in an eLearning course in odoo to complete the previous category before being able to access the next category.

Here is my python code building a boolean that will allow access to a given slide.

```
class Slide(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'slide.slide'

    def _previous_category_complete(self):
        for slide in self.filtered(lambda s: s.category_id):
            slide.previous_category_complete = slide.previous_category_complete()

    previous_category_complete = fields.Boolean('Previous Category Complete', compute=_previous_category_complete)

    def all_quizes_complete(self):
        partner_id = self.env.user.partner_id
        quizes_in_category = self.env['slide.slide'].search([('category_id','=',self.id),('slide_type','=','quiz')])
        quizes_partner_relation = self.env['slide.slide.partner'].search([
                                    ('partner_id','=',partner_id.id),
                                    ('slide_id','in',quizes_in_category.mapped('id'))]) if quizes_in_category else False
        if quizes_partner_relation:
            return all(quiz.complete for quiz in quizes_partner_relation)
        return self.previous_category_complete()

    def previous_category_complete(self):
        previous_category = self.env['slide.slide'].search([
            ('category_id','=',False),
            ('channel_id','=',self.channel_id),
            ('sequence', '<', self.category_id.sequence)]).sorted('sequence', reverse=True)[0]
        return previous_category.all_quizes_complete() if previous_category else True
```

And here is the xml that I believe should grant access to a given slide.

```
  <template id="mdlu_lesson_card" inherit_id='website_slides.lesson_card'>
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-set='can_access']" position="replace">
      <t t-set="can_access" t-value="slide.previous_category_complete and slide.is_preview or channel.is_member or channel.can_publish "/>
    </xpath>
  </template>

  <template id="mdlu_slide_fullscreen_sidebar_category" inherit_id='website_slides.slide_fullscreen_sidebar_category'>
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-set='can_access']" position="replace">
      <t t-set="can_access" t-value="slide.previous_category_complete and slide.is_preview or channel.is_member or channel.can_publish "/>
    </xpath>
  </template>

  <template id="mdlu_slide_aside_training_category" inherit_id='website_slides.slide_aside_training_category'>
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-set='can_access']" position="replace">
      <t t-set="can_access" t-value="slide.previous_category_complete and slide.is_preview or channel.is_member or channel.can_publish "/>
    </xpath>
  </template>
```

However when I use this xml code I'm not hitting any breakpoints in my python code and i'm getting errors.  If, I set the `can_access` variable using `and` (like above) I get this error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_member'
Template: website_slides.slide_fullscreen_sidebar_category
Path: /t/li/ul/t/t[3]
Node: <t t-set="can_access" t-value="slide.previous_category_complete and slide.is_preview or channel.is_member or channel.can_publish "/>
```

and if I use `or` I get:

```
Error:


Traceback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined
    at Class._pushUrlState (http://192.168.1.19:8069/web/content/1107-ab2dd33/1/web.assets_frontend_lazy.js:477:355)
    at Class._onChangeSlide (http://192.168.1.19:8069/web/content/1107-ab2dd33/1/web.assets_frontend_lazy.js:481:101)
    at http://192.168.1.19:8069/web/content/1107-ab2dd33/1/web.assets_frontend_lazy.js:475:70
```

Could someone please help me work this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`channel` is not defined in `website_slides.slide_fullscreen_sidebar_category`, to access the channel attributes you need to use the `slide.channel_id` reference.

[is_member](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/website_slides/views/website_slides_templates_lesson_fullscreen.xml#L83) is defined just before the `can_access` variable, you can use it instead of `slide.channel_id.is_member`.

Odoo will raise the same error when rendering the `website_slides.slide_aside_training_category` template.

To fix that error you can simply replace the `channel` with `slide.channel_id` in both templates like following:

***slide_fullscreen_sidebar_category***

```
<template id="mdlu_slide_fullscreen_sidebar_category" inherit_id='website_slides.slide_fullscreen_sidebar_category'>
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-set='can_access']" position="replace">
        <t t-set="can_access" t-value="slide.previous_category_complete and slide.is_preview or is_member or slide.channel_id.can_publish "/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

***slide_aside_training_category***:

```
<template id="mdlu_slide_aside_training_category" inherit_id='website_slides.slide_aside_training_category'>
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-set='can_access']" position="replace">
        <t t-set="can_access" t-value="slide.previous_category_complete and slide.is_preview or is_member or slide.channel_id.can_publish "/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

The [compute](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields) is the name of the function to compute the field value as a string.

If it uses the values of other fields, it should specify those fields using `depends()`.

```
previous_category_complete = fields.Boolean(string='Previous Category Complete',
                                            compute='_previous_category_complete')
```

Comment: This fixed the errors.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the errors.  I can't get the variable to trigger though.  Am I looking in the completely wrong place for this?

Comment: Which variable? If you need to trigger the compute when some fields values change, you will need to specify those fields using the [depends](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.api.depends) decorator.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the '`channel`', where you do not have the recordset. so it will not work to access that model in another field like this channel.is_member.Although you can add the condition like this,

```
<t t-set="can_access" t-value="slide.previous_category_complete and slide.is_preview or channel and (channel.is_member or channel.can_publish)"/>
```

Make sure you have the id of the channel, later you can access all the fields belong to the same model.